# If Roger is fired from the cannon with an angle of inclination θ of 60° and that he hits...

Tags: physics

If Roger is fired from the cannon with an angle of inclination θ of 60° and that he hits the ground 1/2 mile from the cannon. What, then, was Roger's initial speed?

Comment: what is the acceleration due to gravity? what simplifying assumptions do we make? and more importantly, what have *you* tried?

Comment: acceleration due to gravity is 9.8m/s^2. I'm only able to get as far as using y(t)=-(1/2)gt^2 + (vsinθ)t + h, where g and theta and h are known but not sure what to use for t. @Sabyasachi

Answer (score 1):

We have been given the range here. So we can go forward with:
$$R = \frac{v^2Sin2θ}{g}$$

where,

R = Range in Km, here given 1/2 miles which is = [0.804672 Km](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1/2%20mile%20km&oq=1/2%20mile%20km&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0.3075j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) = 804.672 m

v = Initial Velocity which we need to find.

θ = $60^0$

g = [9.80665](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) $m/s^2$

Now the v value can be easily calculated which is the initial velocity.

Comment: Thanks. Got 95.4 m/s for v initial.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the acceleration of gravity is $g$, the time for hiting the ground is $t$, and the initial speed is $v$, then we have the velocity components are
$$v_x=v\cos(60^\circ)=\frac{v}{2}\\v_y=v\sin(60^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}v}{2}$$
According to the formulas of velocity and accelerration, we have the equations:
$$v_xt=\frac{1}{2}\\v_y=g\frac{t}{2}$$
then
$$vt=1\\\sqrt{3}v=gt$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$t=\frac{1}{v}\\\sqrt{3}v^2=g$$
so $$v=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: Why is theta 60 degrees

Comment: you give that the angle of inclination θ is $60^\circ$, so $v_x=v\cos(60^\circ)=v\sin(30^\circ)$

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask why is it 30 before you edited it. Thanks though.

Comment: It's just the relationship beween the right-angle sides and the hypotenuse in a right-angled triangle. I wrote $30$ because $30=90-60$, it's not a problem if you want to write 60